# I can't figure out how to install Minecraft.tar.gz due to there being no install, configure, or readme file

Tags: linux, software-installation, raspberry-pi

I am having almost the exact same problem. When I try to run the executable file I get this error:

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
```

The executable file does nothing when I try to execute it in file manager too.

The file I am installing is `Minecraft.tar.gz`. I have been trying to install Minecraft for a while. I have spent about 72 hours over the course of about a month trying to install it, to no avail. I am hoping that this `.tar.gz` file is the answer to my problems. I just don't know how to install it since there is no install, configure, or README file.

Just in case you need to know, the OS that I am using is Raspbian X
(basically Linux).

help please?

---

please forget i said "the exact same problem". yes i am trying to install the launcher. i have already tryed the debian launcher with many different methods and none of them have fully worked. in the file there is a single file named minecraft-launcher. in that file there is a few other files. these are them:

```
locales
cef.pak
cef_100_percent.pak
cef_200_percent.pak
cef_extensions.pak
chrome-sandbox
icudtl.dat
libcef.so
libgconf-2.so.4
liblauncher.so
minecraft-launcher
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
v8_context_snapshot.bin
```

the file named `minecraft-launcher` is the executable. but does nothing when i try to execute it in file manager or terminal. i am trying to install full minecraft not barebones minecraft pi. i already have that installed and its just not the same as full blown minecraft java.
i appreciate the help.

---

the thing is though, minecraft pi isn't the full version. i downloaded the tarball file from the minecraft website and it is listed under "other linux". i am saying "linux" or "raspbian" because rasbian x is based off of linux. its mainly a mix of linux (i dont know which version, looks like a couple of different versions) and rasbian.

Comment: You do not mention the contents of `Minecraft.tar.gz` or what executables you are trying to run, so I can only give generic advice.  A Minecraft server is normally distributed as a [single JAR file](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server), I have not seen it officially distributed in a `tar.gz` so make sure you have a legal copy.  The only dependency of a Minecraft server would be the correct version of the Java Runtime on your Raspbian.  You should just need to run the Minecraft server JAR using java: `java -server -jar path/to/downloaded/server.jar`.

Comment: Any .tar.gz is a complete package. The normal method is to create a fresh directory for the package (and named after it), and unload the archive into it. The top level of the sub-directory should include a readme, release notes, possibly a .configure file and a makefile. Strong recommendation to list the archive to ensure it only unloads files with relative filenames (so it can't get you to unload malware). List the contents with `tar -tvz Minecraft.tar.gz > MC.list` and review the list. Then `tar -xz Minecraft.tar.gz` and explore the directory.

Comment: You are having almost the exact same problem as what? When you try to run *what* executable file? Please include enough information in your question to allow people to understand it fully without reading anything else. If your problem is related to some other problem, add a link to that one. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: From where did you get that `Minecraft.tar.gz` file? You might be interested in [Minecraft Pi Edition](https://www.minecraft.net/edition/pi) which was specifically made for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You downloaded the wrong variant. You are trying to execute a binary for the x86-64 (standard PC) architecture. Raspbian X for the Raspberry Pi is ARM. Check @Devon's comment for a link to the correct variant.

Comment: the thing is though, minecraft pi isn't the full version. i downloaded the tarball file from the minecraft website and it is listed under "other linux". i am saying "linux" or "raspbian" because rasbian x is based off of linux. its mainly a mix of linux (i dont know which version, looks like a couple of different versions) and rasbian.

Comment: Raspian (based on Debian) is a flavour of Linux. The system architecture is something else completely. Think of the flavour like a certain brand of car (Audi, Toyota, Volvo). The architecture is the class of car (compact, lorry, tractor). Your question is akin to "where to get a hopper for my sedan? I can only fit a bucket in the trunk.". The application needs to be compiled specifically for the target architecture. Unless Minecraft is provided for ARM, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install a minecraft server or just the launcher?  I believe Minecraft.tar.gz is the launcher.  If that's the case, depending on your platform, you might be able to use the debian one at https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative which is an automated install.